# How to copy meta_value of wp_usermeta to the same table however different meta_key?

Tags: sql, wordpress, copy

I am trying to copy the first name to the display name. I created a temporary table call wp_tmp_usermeta. And did a join. However, no rows affected. Whhyyyyyyyy?

Error Message:  0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0213 seconds.)

```
UPDATE
    `wp_usermeta`
JOIN (SELECT `meta_value`,`user_id` FROM `wp_tmp_usermeta` WHERE `wp_tmp_usermeta`.`meta_key` = 'first_name') newtable ON newtable.`user_id` = `wp_usermeta`.`user_id`
SET
    `wp_usermeta`.meta_value = newtable.meta_value
WHERE
    `wp_usermeta`.meta_key = 'nickname'  ;
```

Desired result is to copy the value of first_name to nickname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy (i.e. really duplicate the rows) the first name but keyed as nickname, you don't need a temporary table and no `UPDATE`. You want an `INSERT ... SELECT`.

```
INSERT INTO wp_usermeta
            (meta_key,
             meta_value,
             user_id)
            SELECT 'nickname',
                   meta_value,
                   user_id
                   FROM wp_usermeta
                   WHERE meta_key = 'first_name';
```

Comment: how about the user id? will it sychronise?

Comment: @SapienElva: I edit the answer to also have a column `user_id` in. And that's why you should **always** provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Had you posted a [example], I hadn't missed that so easily.

Comment: Thanks! It works! Okay noted on the minimal reproducible example